# Open new terminal window with written something without press Enter mac

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to open a new terminal window with "hello world" without the command being pressed, ie without pressing enter

I open the new window of the terminal but I can not write "Hello World".

How can it be done?

The code (in Script Editor):

```
do shell script "open -a Terminal"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hoping for the user to subsequently be able to press `Enter/Return` and that the command will then run? Or not?

Comment: That's right. I hope the user then press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does as you asked:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using {command down}
        keystroke "Hello World"
    end tell
end tell
```

**Note:** Adjust the value of the `delay` *command* as appropriate for the timing on your system.

You can also use the following, if you prefer:

```
do shell script "open -a Terminal"
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "k" using {command down}
    keystroke "Hello World"
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect.

Comment: If before writing "hello world" I wanted to launch the command clear how to do it?

Comment: @LightGreen, I've updated my answer for your comment about the `clear` _command_,